# How to unit test static class Rhino mocks

Tags: c#, unit-testing, rhino-mocks

I have legacy code that I need to unit test without changing.Some parts are not testable.I am using Rhinomocks,I am stuck at how to create a mock of static class and verify any expectation on it.Here is the example code:

```
  public static class BadGuy
{
    private static event Badevent;

}

public class GoodGuy
{
    public GoodGuy()
    {
        BadGuy.Badevent += GoodGuyBadluck;
    }

    private GoodGuyBadluck()
    {
    ....
    }

}
```

Answer (score 1):

RhinoMocks won't mock static classes. If you can abstract your static classes so they sit inside mockable classes then you can use a framework such as Microsoft Moles, TypeMock or JustMock to mock them.

Answer (score 0):

If you can exclude the static class from your unit test, you can create a fake implementation and insert your own stub to monitor activity. Something like this:

```
///
/// My fake implementation
///
public static class BadGuy
{
    private static event Badevent;
    public static void TriggerEvent()
    {
         Badevent();
    }
}
```